# Is there a more succinct way to write this simple snippet?

Tags: haskell

So I am trying to learn haskell and when playing with the Maybe type I came up with this simple code snippet

```
import Data.Maybe
betterDouble :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
betterDouble x =
    case x of
         Just y -> Just (y * 2)
         Nothing -> Nothing
```

This seems clunky and verbose. I cant help but feel there is a more succinct way of writing this in haskell. What is an idiomatic or succinct way I could rewrite that code block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Maybe` is a Functor, you can use `fmap` to map over its contents:

```
betterDouble = fmap (* 2)
```

Comment: [Recommended LYAH reading](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).

Comment: @Alex Thats what I was reading, though i didnt get to the chapter you suggested. I was still confused as to how to effectively use the Maybe type class. Took me a while to even get the snippet of code I showed to work, and when i did it seemed "silly" and useless. But now i know better :)

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman `Maybe` is a workhorse in that book... more functionality (e.g. applicative functor/monad uses) are shown in even later chapters.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, looking forward to it. Though I think they could have done a better job at introducing Maybe by at least showing  a bit more basic usage. But hey the book has been golden up until this point so its a minor critique. I'm sure things will make more sense as I continue.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman You are basically asking "Why didn't they talk about functors before they introduced functors?" There's very little to `Maybe` beyond what you correctly used in your question without learning about the type classes of which `Maybe` is an instance of.

Comment: @chepner Well wasnt the functor part i was expecting so much. Simply that they introduced Maybe without showing how a function could take Maybe as an argument and use it in some way. I have no issue with the idea that functors themselves came much later.

Comment: I feel like `Maybe`'s reputation preceded it for you. LYAH gives an example of how to pattern match on a custom data type immediately after introducing the `data` keyword. In the case of `Maybe`, you just extend that to `betterDouble Nothing = Nothing` and `betterDouble (Just y) = Just (y * 2)`. (The pair of preceding definitions is just syntactic sugar, by the way, for the solution you came up with.)

Comment: @chepner Yea I see that now. What had confused me at the time was the Nothing. Once I realized how to do it (from the previous hints in the book) it made sense. But for a minute there it was very confusing and was struggling to figure it out. I think its just the case that a noobie for the language is much more easily confused than makes sense for someone who understands it. For now the whole thing feels counter intuitive but im sure with time that will change, I'm just used to other languages.